# Get Comma Separated Value in Solr from Field

Tags: xpath, solr, concatenation

I have xml like this.

```
<Root>
    <a1>
     <a>test</a>
     <b>
       <c>1</c>
       <c>2</c>
     </b>
    </a1>

    <a1>
     <a>test2</a>
     <b>
       <c>3</c>
       <c>4</c>
     </b>
    </a1>
</Root>
```

I will import data from this xml into solr.

I am using XPathEntityProcessor and I want to concate values of nodes `<c>`.
Which will result in "1,2" and "3,4".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Would definitely be possible and easy using XPath 2.0, are you bound to solr (which even seems to support an XPath 1.0 *subset* only)?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** with XPath in solr.

This query will work with any XPath 2.0-compatible query processors, which solr doesn't seem to be:

```
//b/string-join(c/text(), ",")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jend Erat , for your reply, Now I am not sure which version I am using, Can you guide me , how to check version of XPath?

Comment: If this code works, it will be XPath 2.0, otherwise 1.0. ;) I couldn't find any definite information in a swift search, but if they don't advertise XPath 2.0, they won't support it.

Comment: I'd retract that bold part. :-) Most of the things are possible with enough elbow grease, as Solr includes a lot of extension points.

Comment: Respecified it to solr's XPath support where it definitly will not be possible (as long as it reallye is an XPath *subset* which it says). But you're right, there are probably lots of ways to work around that, but I answered the question which is about XPath in solr.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to concatenate them? Solr supports multivalued fields out of the box, you just need to declare them that way.

However, if you really do want to do, use DIH to put them into multiValued field and then concat them either with custom/script transformer or with (Solr 4+) update.chain and [Update Request Processor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor). There is [one that can concatenate](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html).

Comment: Actually , I am having that kind of requirement, for that particular field(multivalued), I need to show them as comma separated.